# PHP and C# MD5 crypt does not give the same output?

Tags: c#, php, encryption, authentication, crypt

This is the encryption I have when people register on my site:

```
$salt = generateSalt();
$hashedPassword = crypt($userPass, $salt);
```

and here is my `generateSalt` function:

```
function generateSalt() {
    $salt = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
    $salt = '$1$' . $salt;
    return $salt;
}
```

When I encrypt a password with this I get for example:

> $1$92999442$AK4yZPjnj6BKc9yj4CXKu1

But when  I crypt the same password on C# with this function:

```
hashedPassword = GenerateMD5(uName, salt);
```

GenerateMD5 function:

```
    public String GenerateMD5(String input, String salt)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + salt);
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5Cng md5hashstring = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5Cng();
        byte[] hash = md5hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        return hex;
    }
```

I get a complete different output. With the same password and the same salt I get this output:

> 9DE11D48C3F7DF1BF89FC76D755A2596

What function should I use in PHP and C# to get the same output?

Comment: I had a similar issue with Delphi and PHP and it was a problem of padding (some \0 at the end of the hash), maybe exploring this possibility will help you solve this problem. Otherwise it can come from a possible default IV which is different from C# to PHP. Good luck !

Comment: You use `crypt()` in PHP and MD5 in C#... Of course this will lead into different results ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using two completely different algorithms. In PHP you're using `crypt()` which uses DES, and in C# you're using MD5. They're never going to produce the same output. If you want the same output, you should use `md5()` in PHP instead of `crypt()`

Also, don't use MD5, it's deprecated. You should be using at least SHA-2 now

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/md5

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2006/10/09/how-do-i-calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string_3f00_.aspx

and adding a random salt to your input is part of them problem. you'll end up with a different input every time, hence a different hash output.

Comment: I am using the same salt on both encodings

Comment: you are using mt_rand.  how is it the same?

Comment: The first one is the register function. I save that salt in the database and then when someone login on the c# application it gets that salt and encrypt it with that

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd consider using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead. Does all that `crypt` work for you in a nice, neat package, complete with random salt.

As to why your function doesn't match, you're using MD5 in your C# code. I'm no expert in C# but you should use some sort of bcrypt hashing system. There is an [open source bcrypt for C#](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/) that might do the trick for you. In theory, since they use the same system, one should be able to validate the other since they all store the salt in the string. Just pluck the salt from the string and plug the password and salt into the other one and they should match.

Answer (score 0):

This is so called [md5crypt](http://phk.freebsd.dk/sagas/md5crypt.html) by Poul-Henning Kamp, not to be confused with MD5. Md5crypt for first used to protect FreeBSD passwords from bruteforce, but then became more widespread. It was incorporated into GNU libc crypt() and many programs had interfaces to this system call, including PHP, and some PHP developers made use of it. Md5crypt invokes MD5 no less than 1000 times to make brute-force harder (but nowadays [md5crypt is considered outdated by its author!](http://phk.freebsd.dk/sagas/md5crypt_eol.html)). I have seen implementation of md5crypt for many programming languages, [this one is for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20767/Unix-md-crypt).